# how to pass a swift Array as UnsafePointer<T> argument in a function

Tags: arrays, swift, unsafe-pointers

I read that in order to pass a swift variable/constant to an argument that expects UnsafePointer can be done by using the 'inout' (ampersand) symbol prefixing the variable/constant. 
So in the following code, I want to pass the 'colors' array as "UnsafePointer' to the function CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(), but I get a compiler error:

"& used with non-inout argument of type UnsafePointer"

See image below for visual.

So, the question is , how can I convert the swift array 'colors' into an UnsafePointer ?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your colors type to be explicitly `[CGFloat]`:

```
var colors : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

No need to deal with `&` or anything. But you have to actually pass in an array of `CGFloat`.

And don't pass in `NULL` but `nil`:

```
let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, nil, 2)
```

Comment: Hi luk, I explicitly declare colors as a CGFloat array, but I get , although different error message, still related message to passing the wrong argument type:  "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CGFloat>'"

Comment: @malena hm, what kind of error this time? For some reason my Playground compiles fine

Comment: @malena ah, yeah, forget about that one - the `NULL` is the problem

Comment: righto, i just discovered that the NULL is the problem myself. Thank you!

Comment: doesn't answer the question: how do you pass in an Array to an UnsafePointer<T>

Comment: @johnrubythecat I **did** answer the question in the sense that I proposed the actual solution to the problem. If that does not satisfy you, go ahead and post a question of your own. This post is obviously not the correct place for you.

Comment: It Just Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
struct GradientPoint {
  var location: CGFloat
  var color: UIColor
}

gradientPoints.flatMap { $0.color.cgColor.components }.flatMap { $0 }
```